# Can Ubuntu put a running thread to sleep because it was inactive for a long time?

Tags: 18.04, python3

I have a python thread that spends most of its time sleeping, it wakes once every 30 seconds to upload some files then goes back to sleep,  does Ubuntu put it in permanent sleep because it does not use a lot of CPU time or something?

you can find more more details about the python code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924060/thread-goes-to-infinite-sleep)

Answer (score 1):

The generic call to `sleep` would result in a timer being set and the scheduler effectively forgetting about your task until the termination of the timer causing the scheduler to put your task back on its "stuff to do" list. The CPU is yielded to the system until needed again.

Comment: Makes sense, but that still doesn't explain why the thread goes to infinite sleep, does this mean that the error is in the timer? does it not end or never puts the task back on the scheduler after it ends? any ideas on how I would debug it more?

Comment: I missed that you were ending up in some infinite hang. The error is somewhere in your code, not in the timer. I would start adding debug print flags to the code in an attempt to determine where it is hanging.